# Integral over a product

Tags: calculus, integration, products, hypergeometric-function

How the following integral can be computed:

$I = \int_0^1 (x-a_1)^{b_1}(x-a_2)^{b_2}...(x-a_n)^{b_n} dx$?

Here, $a_i,b_i$ are real numbers and $n$ is a natural number. Are there any techniques for computing this integral? I know that if $n=2$, a Special case will be the Beta function. Some hypergeometric functions can be obtained from this integral over a product. But what is for General $n$?

Comment: You need the [Lauricella Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauricella_hypergeometric_series#Integral_representation_of_FD).